# Migrating to Graph Api from Exchange webservice

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices

I am trying to migrate a mail box to cloud and i am required to update from Microsoft exchange webservices to Microsoft Graph API in my application which connects to the mail box. Does this mean i need to rebuild my whole application with the Graph API dependencies or is it possible to only update the authentication?

Answer (score 0):

At this time, you would only need to change your EWS application to authenticate using OAuth2 (AKA Modern Auth).  MSFT says that sometime around mid-year 2021 EWS for cloud mailboxes will no longer be able to authenticate with Basic (user/password) auth, so your app could just stop working one day.  AFAIK, MSFT has not announced the date when this will happen, but they will likely give advanced notice.

That said, this might be a good time to consider rewriting the app to use the Graph API.  MSFT has not said they intend to kill off EWS, so with Modern Auth you should be able to continue for some time, but if your app is intended to live for several more years, it would be strategic to convert it over to Graph.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to use the Graph API instead of EWS API due to a project or customer requirement and not because the Basic auth will be deprecated in EWS.

If I'm correct than I would migrate the whole logic from EWS to Graph - especially when you intend to work further in O365 environment as EWS is deprecated already- meaning that it won't receive new implementation or future bug fixes.